# What to make of these abrt-list errors?

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, hardware-compatibility, abrt

I keep getting a warning every time I switch to root.

> ABRT has detected 'x' problems(s). For more info run arbt-cli list.

And 'arbt-cli list' lists the same problem over and over again:

```
id b34c40c7bb83544557c2f0e9159dac1b6f0fe248
reason:         mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
time:           Thu 10 Aug 2017 01:18:58 PM EDT
cmdline:        BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
package:        kernel
uid:            0 (root)
count:          1
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/oops-2017-08-10-13:18:58-4298-0
Reported:       cannot be reported
```

There was only one time in which there was a different problem that occured:

```
id d51f71a530d663d892e6ad34c2e0fc8908e7b527
reason:         Gio.py:171:__call__:Error: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2 (19)
time:           Wed 09 Aug 2017 10:49:48 PM EDT
cmdline:        /usr/bin/python /usr/libexec/initial-setup/initial-setup-graphical --no-stdout-log
package:        initial-setup-gui-0.3.9.36-1.el7.centos
uid:            0 (root)
count:          1
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/Python-2017-08-09-22:49:48-1072
```

I do not know what to make of this.

I installed CentOS 7 on a Inspiron 7000 50 Gaming. It's brand new, so I don't understand why it would be having hardware problems already.

Answer (score 1):

> A Machine Check Exception (MCE) is a type of computer hardware error that occurs when a computer's central processing unit detects a hardware problem.

If you didn't notice any crash, probably the error was successfully corrected. Still, you should install mcelog to keep track of such events:

```
sudo yum install mcelog -y
```

The events will be logged to /var/log/mcelog. You can also run:

```
sudo mcelog --client
```

The second error is coming from the `initial-setup-gui-0.3.9.36-1.el7.centos` package.

```
systemctl disable initial-setup-text.service
```